# Switch Case in Python

Tags: python

It seems like all the functions are executed then one() is being executed.
How do i go to function one() without executing all the other functions?

sample.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def zero():
    print("This is func zero")
    return "Test"

def one():
    print("This is func one")
    return True

def two():
    print("This is func two")
    x = 7
    print("%d" % x)
    return False

def numbers_to_strings(argument): 
    switcher = { 
        0: zero(), 
        1: one(), 
        2: two(), 
    } 

    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing") 

# Driver program 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    argument=1
    print(numbers_to_strings(argument))
```

**Output**

```
This is func zero
This is func one
This is func two
7
True
```

**Expected**

```
This is func one
True
```

Or is there an explanation why it works this way? 
Thanks in advance! New to Python btw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parentheses call the function.

So only use parentheses on the function you want to call.

```
def numbers_to_strings(argument): 
    switcher = { 
        0: zero, 
        1: one, 
        2: two, 
    } 

    f = switcher.get(argument)
    if f:
        return f()
    return "nothing"
```

Comment: Or: `switcher.get(argument, lambda: "nothing")`, after which you can simply `return f()`, since the default will be a function that when called with no arguments produces the expected `"nothing"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's it!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def zero():
    print("This is func zero")
    return "Test"

def one():
    print("This is func one")
    return True

def two():
    print("This is func two")
    x = 7
    print("%d" % x)
    return False

def numbers_to_strings(argument): 
    switcher = { 
        0: zero, 
        1: one, 
        2: two, 
    } 

    f = switcher.get(argument)
    if f:
        return f()
    return "nothing"

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    argument=1
    print(numbers_to_strings(argument))
```